# How convert sequelize relation into prisma relation?

Tags: next.js, model, sequelize.js, relational-database, prisma

Hello I try to change my ORM and I have I problem with my relation.
I want to pass my sequelize ORM to prisma ORM.
This is my sequelize model :

Meeting :

```
const Meeting = connect.define('meeting', {
    id: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    timestamps: false,
})
```

User :

```
const User = connect.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    meetingId: {
        type: DataType.UUID,
        allowNull: true
    },
},
{
  freezeTableName: true,
  createdAt: false,
  updatedAt: false,
  timestamps: false,
})
```

And association :

```
Meeting.hasOne(User);
User.belongsTo(Meeting);
```

So how to convert this in prisma relation model
For the moment I do this :

```
model User {
  id        Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  meeting  Meeting[]
  meetingId Int?
}

model Meeting {
  id       Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int
}
```

But I want to have in User model (meetingId) the references of Meeting (id)
I try to add a new relation but I have many error.
A Meeting can belong to only one User
A User can belong to only one Meeting

Like in sequelize.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the schema below to represent the relationship you defined

```js
model User {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  meeting Meeting?
}

model Meeting {
  id     Int  @id @default(autoincrement())
  user   User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int  @unique
}
```

The `userId` relation scalar is a direct representation of the foreign key in the underlying database. This one-to-one relation expresses the following:

- "A user can have zero meeting or one meeting" (because the `meeting` field is optional on `User`).
- "A meeting must always be connected to one user"

The `user` relation field of the `Meeting` model references the id field of the `User` model.

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-one-relations) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

For generate the same table, I use this `npx prisma db pull`.
It's work perfectly